# How to highlight (or make larger) connection points in Visio?

Tags: microsoft-visio, diagrams

I have two questions:

1. How to make connection points in Visio larger, or highlighted as in this example?
2. How to make description bubble as in the example?

Example of a server with large connection porin and description
[image]

Currently, I can only add connection point to stencil and it is too small,

look at my work here
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The yellow dots are Control points. Select the shape and open the shape's shapesheet, scroll down to the Controls section and you will see 14 control points, one of which is a movable control to move the shape's text label, the others are all located at a guarded location so they cannot be moved. As it happens these controls are at the same location as 13 connection points so when you try to drag a connector over these points the connector shows glueing to these points, so it looks like the connector is glueing to the control. But they are a good way of showing where the connection points are since Microsoft decided to make it very difficult to see connection points.

Comment: Thank you, It is the correct answer. I have one more question. How can I add control points via mouse? Is it somewhere in top ribbon menu? When I have stencil without any control point, I cannot add it in shapesheet.

Comment: Use the Connection Point tool, the blue cross to the right of the Connector tool. In Visio 2016 it has become extremely difficult to use as you can no longer see where existing connection points are!

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot change the appearance of connection points.
2. **Insert** -> **Callout** and select the type you want. There are more callout shapes in the stencil called **Callouts** in the **Extras** section.

Comment: OK, but how are connection points created in the stencil in the first image? (light yellow dots)

Comment: Those yellow dots are not connection points. I don't know what they are, probably part of the diagram, not a standard Visio drawing item I'd only be able to tell by inspection. Go to my website, to the contact page and send me a message, I will then respond so you get my email address and you can send me a file for me to look at. (or the email address is visible on the contact page, but not as copyable text)

Comment: Those yellow dots are control points. In earlier versions of Visio they were small yellow diamond shape, but their appearance has been changed in later versions.